# How to check an activity and bring it to front if it is in Backstack

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have read many questions about backstack and task, But I am not getting them in right way in my problem. I have an issue and that is I have a multi instance activity (declared in manifiest). which could be opened multiple time by the service.This activity has a button which would take user to another activity (Lets say Result Activity) , but before moving to Result Activity I really want to check if this multi instance activity has any instance in backstack, I want to check it so that if there is activity then before moving to that Result activity I should navigate to the other instance of this activity until all instance of this activity is visited by the user , and once all the instance has been visited then on last instance user is now able to navigate to Result activity .  So How Can I do that , I have read the follwoing code but I do not know how can I use it .

```
    // Get the Activity Manager
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // Get a list of running tasks, we are only interested in the last one,
    // the top most so we give a 1 as parameter so we only get the topmost.
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> task = manager.getRunningTasks(1);

    // Get the info we need for comparison.
    ComponentName componentInfo = task.get(0).topActivity;

    // Check if it matches our package name.
    if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(PackageName))
        return true;

    // If not then our app is not on the foreground.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @2Dee,TGMCians,gunr2171,Zero Piraeus,TylerH  look I got answer and that works for me , Please think twice before down rating the question if you have mind . Thanks in advance (PeeeeeP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do what you want is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Try this. This should work.

Comment: In this code I think that A.class is the result class?

Comment: how this will work ?

Comment: If you create an `Intent` with the flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, then the multi instance `Activity` will be started as the root of the current task (i.e. all other activities will be removed from the backstack). On the other hand, if you create an `Intent` with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running. I have added the `Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND` flag as you are starting your `Activity` from a `Service`.

Comment: @zygotelnit I appreciate your help , I think you didnt unerstand my case. In My case , I just wanted user to not to navigate to Result activity unless he presses the Ok button on each multi instance activity which is on back stack . The reason for doing this is , on Ok button the there is a code who would put the data into database , so I want to take user to every single instance of that class and to make him to press ok button until and unless he is on last instance of that multi instance class and when he is on last instance on pressing ok button he would navigated to Result activity .

Comment: Now you got my point @zygotelnit

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT** to bring your activity to front.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT );
startActivity(i);
```

Refer [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)